# In tidyr version 1.0.0, how to simplify nested columns to lists?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I just noticed a switch in the behavior of `nest()` with the updated tidyr. Previously, if you nested a single column, it would return a list column, which made it easy to search within  said list to, say, grab the "highest" classification. For example:

```
tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,   ~c,   ~class,   ~lots_of_other_vars,
  1,    100,  150,  "lowest",  "blah",
  1,    100,  150,  "medium",  "blah",
  1,    100,  150,  "highest", "blah",
  2,    5000, 5500, "lowest",  "blah",
  2,    5000, 5500, "medium",  "blah",
  3,    342,  350,  "lowest",  "blah"
) %>% 
  nest(class) %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(
    "highest" %in% data ~ "highest",
    "medium" %in% data ~ "medium",
    TRUE ~ "lowest"
  ))
```

Unfortunately, instead of returning a simple list, the newest version of the nest function returns a dataframe inside of a list (`list(df[,1])`), breaking my code.

Of course, I can `group_by` everything else to get a similar result:

```
tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,   ~c,   ~class,   ~lots_of_other_vars,
  1,    100,  150,  "lowest",  "blah",
  1,    100,  150,  "medium",  "blah",
  1,    100,  150,  "highest", "blah",
  2,    5000, 5500, "lowest",  "blah",
  2,    5000, 5500, "medium",  "blah",
  3,    342,  350,  "lowest",  "blah"
) %>% 
  group_by_at(vars(-class)) %>% 
  mutate(overall_class = case_when(
    "highest" %in% class ~ "highest",
    "medium" %in% class ~ "medium",
    TRUE ~ "lowest"
  )) %>% 
  select(-class) %>% 
  distinct()
```

However, this is a simplified scenario and I would prefer to keep around the list of classes to take a look at later. Given the changes to `nest`, what's the easiest way to get a list of the values of class while calling distinct on the other variables (i.e. what nest used to do)?

## Edit

This is what I would like plus a column with the list of all classes observed for that site:

```
     a     b     c lots_of_other_vars highest_support
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <chr>          
1     1   100   150 blah               highest        
2     2  5000  5500 blah               medium         
3     3   342   350 blah               lowest
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just reading up on that. It's a solid band-aid for old scripts I'm not going to modify further, but I'd prefer to understand and adapt to the new syntax for code here on out.

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  Why you are changing 'highest" to "highest"?

Comment: Can you show your expected as i think the `case_when` logic is incorrect

Comment: It's based on experimental methods of support for a given set of coordinates. In this particular case, the method with stronger support was only evaluated if the weaker support method was positive for that site. However, I'm integrating a new type of data that is an alternate "highest" and not exclusive to or necessarily inclusive with my current "highest". I may switch to a set of Boolean columns, but the way I have it set up now will be the easiest to integrate with my current functions

Comment: The logic is correct. The df was created by binding the supported sites of various experiments, plus the label for which experiment it was. If a site is supported by (aka in the output of) the highest type of experiment, it should receive a label (here, "highest") denoted that. If it was only seen in the medium quality experiment, then it only gets the label that corresponds to medium support. 

In the current data, all that are highest have support from the medium and low quality experiments, but the new alternate highest experiment excludes the medium experiment.

Comment: Okay, can you check my solution

Comment: Add like to add that you can take a new-type nested list, to a good old regular list column using `tidyr::unpack`

Comment: Thanks, @MossaNova, I wasn't aware of unpack. It sounds useful!